Spring WebFlux - How to return Flux response from Handler class
I wanted to implement CRUD operations using Spring WebFlux, in writing both traditional Controllers and new Handler-Route classes. I understand Mono is for 0,1 item, Flux is for 0 to n number of items.
My use case is to fetch a list of Employees from a database and return them as Flux.
I followed this website and it worked fine for writing traditional controllers - https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-webflux/spring-webflux-tutorial/
@RequestMapping(value = { "/findAll"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Flux<Employee> findAll() {
        return employeeService.findAll();
    }

But when I am trying to do the same using Handlers and Routes, I see one error like the following
Route
-----
@Bean
    public RouterFunction<ServerResponse> route3(EmploeeHandler emploeeHandler) {
        System.out.println("findAll2");
        return RouterFunctions.route(GET("/findAll2").and(accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)),
                emploeeHandler::findAll2);
    }

Handler
-------
public Flux<ServerResponse> findAll2(ServerRequest request) {
        return ServerResponse.ok().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .body(employeeService.findAll(), Employee.class);
                
}

Type mismatch: cannot convert from Mono<ServerResponse> to Flux<ServerResponse>

Making Flux to Mono in ServerResponse is solving the issue.I wanted to use Flux because there can be many employees in the database. Can anyone please explain what I am missing here?

Before you dislike, please answer my question first, then dislike if this is not a good question! I posted this question because I an not able to solve the issue. Thank you.

Even if you're streaming many Employee objects (which you are doing with your repository/service call employeeService.findAll()), this is still considered a single response when you put the Flux<Employee> into the response.
Here's a bit of an analogy:
Imagine you're sending a package with multiple items in it. The package itself is a Mono - it's only one package. But the items inside can be seen as a Flux - there can be 0 to n items in it.
That's why changing Flux<ServerResponse> to Mono<ServerResponse> in the handler method signature is actually what you want to do here.
PS: I am not the one who dislikes this question.

So the example given in the link that I provided, which used traditional way of writing controllers, it says - public Flux findAll() {} etc in the controller. Why not Mono here if the response is only one response? @Malvin
